# URL(urll).readText returns null response KOTLIN ANDROID

Tags: android, json, kotlin, url

I have this peace of code:

```
suspend fun getWeatherResponse(locationCode: String, apiKey: String): String? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" +
                "?q=$locationCode&appid=$apiKey"
        val response: String? = try{
            URL(apiUrl).readText(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            null
        }
        return@withContext response
    }
}
```

and it is supposed to return JSON string, then I do this with the response:

```
val response = getWeatherResponse(location, apiKey)
    val jsonWeatherObj =
            JSONObject(response ?: "{}")
```

But, the response is `null`. I checked in the debugger, link builds properly. If I build a link by myself and execute it in a browser, then I get a proper response on the screen.

The rest of the code:

```
val main = jsonWeatherObj.getJSONObject("main")
    val sys = jsonWeatherObj.getJSONObject("sys")
    val wind = jsonWeatherObj.getJSONObject("wind")
    val weather = jsonWeatherObj.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0)

    val temp = main.getString("temp")+"°C"
    val tempMin = "Min Temp: " + main.getString("temp_min")+"°C"
    val tempMax = "Max Temp: " + main.getString("temp_max")+"°C"
    val pressure = main.getString("pressure")
    val humidity = main.getString("humidity")
    val sunrise:Long = sys.getLong("sunrise")
    val sunset:Long = sys.getLong("sunset")
    val windSpeed = wind.getString("speed")
    val weatherDescription = weather.getString("description")

    val fullLocationName = jsonWeatherObj.getString("name")+", "+sys.getString("country")
    val updatedAt:Long = jsonWeatherObj.getLong("dt")
    val updatedAtText = "Updated at ${SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(updatedAt*1000))}"

    val sunriseText = SimpleDateFormat(
        "hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(sunrise*1000))
    val sunsetText = SimpleDateFormat(
        "hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(sunset*1000))

    weatherObject.value = WeatherInfo(fullLocationName, temp, tempMin, tempMax, updatedAtText, weatherDescription,
    "", pressure, humidity, windSpeed, sunriseText, sunsetText)
    }
```

I get this exception: `org.json.JSONException: No value for main`
Help, please.

Comment: Any exception ?

Comment: @blackapps In result I'm getting an exception `org.json.JSONException: No value for main`. But, this is because I need to access 'main' in this JSON response.

Comment: @blackapps I've updated my question with the rest of the code

Comment: `catch (ex: Exception){
            null
        }` Is that your null response? If so then you should return e.getMessage() and print stack trace and add some loggings. I asked if you had exceptions? I wanna know if your null comes from this catch.